# Why does req.params return an empty array?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using Node.js and I want to see all of the parameters that have been posted to my script. To get to my function, in my `routes/index.js` I'm doing:

```
app.post('/v1/order', order.create);
```

Then in my function, I have:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
 console.log( req.params );
```

But it's returning an empty array. But when I do:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
 console.log( req.param('account_id') );
```

I get data. So I'm a bit confused as to what's going on here.

Comment: Use `req.query`, example `const { name, 'api-key': apiKey } = req.query`

Answer (score 38, accepted):

req.params only contain the route params, not query string params (from GET) and not body params (from POST). The param() function however checks all three, see:

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.params

Comment: Note that `req.param()` is [deprecated](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.param).

Answer (score 65):

**[req.params](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.params)**
can only get the param of request url in this pattern:`/user/:name`

**[req.query](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query)**
get query params(name) like `/user?name=123` or body params.

Comment: this should be accepted as the answer. thanks

Answer (score 28):

I had a similar problem and thought I'd post the solution to that for those coming here for the same reason. My req.params was coming out as an empty object because I declared the URL variable in the parent route. The solution is to add this option to the router:

```
const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });
```

Comment: Thank you! This took me forever to debug.

Answer (score 1):

With postman, you can have two types of get requests:

1. Using `x-www-form-urlencoded` and passing data through the body.
2. Using url parameters

You can always use this code snippet to always capture the data, no matter how you pass it.

```js
/*
    * Email can be passed both inside a body of a json, or as 
    a parameter inside the url.

    * { email: 'test@gmail.com' } -> test@gmail.com
    * http://localhost/buyer/get/?email=test@gmail.com -> test@gmail.com
        */
    let { email }: { email?: string } = req.query;
    if (!email) email = req.body.email;
        
    console.log(email);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this for your `server.js` or `app.js`:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.