# expressjs not passing req.params through middleware

Tags: express, middleware

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523644/why-does-req-params-return-an-empty-array)

I have the following route:
`app.get('/blogpost/:link', middleware.loginCheck, blog.postBlogs);`

Using `req.params.link` returns the link parameter.
When I ask for the `req.params.link` in `middleware.loginCheck` I receive an `undefined`.

It seems that `req.params.link` is not being passed through to the middleware because I can access it like so:
`app.get('/blogpost/:link', function(req, res){console.log(req.params.link)});`

Whats the problem with my middleware?

**FINAL**
`a(href='/post/#{post.link}') #{comments}` renders `/post/myPostLink`

`{#post.link}` only renders the variable substitute and does not add an extra `/`
`a(href='/post#{post.link}') #{comments}` renders '/postmyPostLink'

`a(href='/post/' + post.link) #{comments}` renders `/post/myPostLink`

So both `#{post.link}` or `post.link` work the same and `req.params.link` works on both calls.

**UPDATE_2**
I am using `jade` to render the web page.  Inside there I have an anchor tag written as so:  `a(href='/post/#{post.link}) #{comments}`
The achor tag works fine and directs me to the correct page.  But `express` does not like this representation.  Instead, if I change the anchor tag to `a(href='/post/' + post.link) #{comments}` `req.params.link` works fine.

**UPDATE_1**
`req.param('link')` works for this case.
There is no problem with the middleware.
But why wouldn't `req.params.link` work?

Comment: Can you post the relevant code for your middleware? I don't see any obvious bugs in the code snippets you have posted. Could be something as simple as a typo in `req.params.link` in `middleware.loginCheck`. Also, are you passing a parameter called 'link' in more than 1 place in the request, such as the query string or request body? If so, it's possible to get data back in `req.params('link')` but not in `req.params.link` because `req.params` is just URL/route parameters whereas `req.param('link')` checks URL params, then body, then query string.

Comment: In `middleware.loginCheck` there is no reference to `req.params.link`.  The only time I call `req.params.link` is in `blog.postBlogs`.  I just need the `req.params.link` to pass all the way through.  I don't think I'm passing a parameter called 'link'.  There is an `<a href="/post/name_of_post">` where `name_of_post` is the `req.params.link`. So when a user clicks that anchor tag it shows up in the URL, then `req.params.link` should pop out?

Answer (score 2):

OK, we went back and forth in the comments a bit, but now my guess is that the problem is double slashes in your URL

```
a(href='/post/#{post.link}') #{comments}
```

That is A) missing a closing quote, but I assume that is a typo just in your question here, not in your code. and B) the real problem is that `post.link` includes a leading slash, so you end up with this HTML:

```
<a href='/post//post_link_name'>42</a>
```

Thus express is parsing that as an empty `:link` parameter. Change your jade to this:

```
a(href='/post#{post.link}') #{comments}
```

and you should get back in business.

Comment: `#{post.link}` and `#{comments}` render correctly in the html.  That is, a(href='/post/#{post.link}') #{comments} render `/post/post_link_name` and `#{comments}` shows a number.  I needed to change it as you have `a(href='/post' + post.link`) in order for express to attach it to `req.params.link`. [see this](http://naltatis.github.com/jade-syntax-docs/#text)

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of *express* you can use `router.param()` as your middleware to specifically work on the `req.params`:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.param( "nickname", function (req, res, next, nickname) {

    console.log( "nickname: ", nickname );
    next();
});

router.get( "/user/:nickname", myController.method );
```

Answer (score -1):

what does the signature of `middleware.loginCheck` look like? It needs to return a `function(req, res, next)`

Comment: It does.  The reason I don't post the middleware is because its really messy.  But it does `function(req, res, next)`

Comment: should work with what you've shown. just another though, it will only be defined in your a `/blogpost/:link` route